# How do I do table locking in GORM(Golang)?

Tags: go, go-gorm

How do I do table locking in GORM(go-gorm)?

I found a way to do [row locking](https://gorm.io/it_IT/docs/advanced_query.html#Locking-FOR-UPDATE), but could not find a way to do table locking.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this code according to [gorm.io](https://gorm.io/it_IT/docs/advanced_query.html#Locking-FOR-UPDATE) docs:

**Row-Level Lock Modes, FOR UPDATE**

```
db.Clauses(clause.Locking{Strength: "UPDATE"}).Find(&users)
// SELECT * FROM `users` FOR UPDATE
```

Also, you could use other lock mode instead of UPDATE, like: `KEY SHARE, SHARE, NO KEY UPDATE.`

**Table-Level Lock Modes**

For locking a table, as far as I can see there is no option with Gorm right now, because Gorm always put FOR, when merging Clauses.
but you can use a raw query to achieve what you want:

```
db.Exec("LOCK TABLE table_name_here IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE")

// LOCK [ TABLE ] [ ONLY ] name [ * ] [, ...] [ IN lockmode MODE ] [ NOWAIT ]
```

where lockmode is one of:

```
ACCESS SHARE | ROW SHARE | ROW EXCLUSIVE | SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE
| SHARE | SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE | EXCLUSIVE | ACCESS EXCLUSIVE
```

**More info on Postgres locks [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES)**

**Add options**

You can use `Options` to add any option that you want, this will be appear after the Strength.

```
db.Clauses(clause.Locking{
  Strength: "UPDATE",
  Options: "NOWAIT",
}).Find(&users)
// SELECT * FROM `users` FOR UPDATE NOWAIT
```

How to unlock:

When you are using `Strength: "UPDATE"`, it means the table is Locking (FOR UPDATE) And it will be unlock after updating.

Some other updates are:

- `Strength: "SHARE"`

Comment: I appreciate your support.

Comment: When does it unlock? How how do you unlock?

Comment: "And it will be unlock after updating"